# Git checkout thinks there are changes while git stash/reset do not find a change

Tags: git

I'm on the develop branch and want to checkout another branch using:

```
$ git checkout [BRANCH_NAME]
```

And get the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        [FILE_NAME]
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

However, when I try to stash [FILE_NAME], I get the following error:

```
git stash save [FILE_NAME]
No local changes to save
```

I have tried git reset --hard as well and still get the same issue. Can't figure out what is causing this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: Git status does not show any changes to that file. There are a few other unrelated untracked files however

Comment: Did you try a simple `git stash` without parameters, to stash all changes to the working tree, rather than specifying your file?

Comment: Git stash also says no local changes to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get this:

> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>         foo.txt
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
> ```

but `git status` does not report anything *about* `foo.txt` being modified, then one of the following must be the case:

- You have a `foo.txt` file but it's not tracked—i.e., it's not in the index *right now*.  The commit you are asking to check out *does* have a tracked `foo.txt`.  Git is warning you that *your* `foo.txt` will be *replaced with* the other commit's tracked `foo.txt`, after which the file will be tracked.  (Remember, the phrase *file X is tracked* means *path X is in the index right now*.  The index contents *change* as you change commits, so the tracked or untracked state of some file can change over time.)
- Or, you have a `foo.txt` that is tracked (is in the index), but you've told Git to `--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree` on that file.  The commit you are asking to check out *does* have a `foo.txt`, and it *doesn't match yours*.  Git is warning you that *your* `foo.txt` will be *replaced with* the other commit's `foo.txt`.

You can't stash or commit the file *because* you've told Git *not to do that* (by having it untracked, or by setting the assume-unchanged or skip-worktree bits).  Git is still giving you a chance to save the contents, though, rather than just rudely clobbering the file from whatever commit you're asking to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the file worked for me. I copied to file to another location and copied it back after the merge.